# use mongoose expires to remove a ref object id from document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

i have 2 schema  TokenSchema and DriverSchema :

```
const tokenSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  token: { type: String, required: true },
  creationDate: { type: Date, required: true, expires: '1m', default: Date.now },
});


const driverSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  drivingLicenseNumber: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }, 
  
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  token: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Token',
  },
});
```

i need to remove the token id ref from the driver then i remove the token object is that possible ?

Comment: It's probably possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: with this code  all the driver document  was removed after 1 minute

Comment: Aaaah, I understand now. The problem is, it's an operation done at index-level, there's no other logic. Really, I have no idea if there's a way to hook the index delete action, and add some logic to remove driver.token at the same time.